# Re-send ajax request until the close of the page

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to re-send the same ajax request until the close of the page with pure javascript (no framework please). Following my code:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post2.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");    
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
  // resend the same request, until the close of the page 
}
```

Comment: Do you need send several times this ajax?

Comment: Yes i do, untile the close of the page.

Comment: Well I think you can use setInterval( your_function, 1000 ), in this way you will call automatically you function each 1000 milliseconds .

Comment: I want to resend the request when the previous one is done.

Comment: Ok, well in this case you can use what @joseeight suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do that, but here you go.

```
// Reusing variable to keep garbage low.
var xhr;
// Recursive request.
function recursiveXHR () {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','demo_post2.asp',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // This is where the method is called again once the previous request is done.
    xhr.addEventListener('load', recursiveXHR, false);
    xhr.send('fname=Henry&lname=Ford');
}
// Initializing the recursive calling.
recursiveXHR();
```